# I need an Amazon S3 user with full access to a single bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, user-permissions, amazon-iam

I have a user foo with the following privileges (it's not a member of any group):

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1308813201865",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

That user however seem unable to upload or do much of anything until I grant full access to authenticated users (which might apply to anyone). This still doesn't let the user change permission as [boto](/questions/tagged/boto) is throwing an error after an upload when it tries to do do `key.set_acl('public-read')`.

Ideally this user would have full access to the `bar` bucket and nothing else, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to grant **s3:ListBucket** permission to the bucket itself. Try the policy below.

```js
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "S3:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bar/*",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bar",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Some nuance: It seems that `bar/*` is needed to access objects inside the `bar` bucket, whereas `bar` is needed to list/modify the bucket itself.

Comment: Using Cyberduck to access S3 with the above permission didn't seem to work.  It may be that Cyberduck needs ListAllMyBuckets as mentioned by @Suman. However if you use the command line tool from [timkay.com](http://www.timkay.com/aws/), this works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks a million. I F$%#@^ING hate s3 with its cumbersome policies. Just wasted 2 hours till I finally found the solution.

Comment: It works in Cyberduck if you set "Path" under "More Options" to the bucket name. Then you don't need to add ListAllMyBuckets.

Comment: Would just like to confirm what @JoarLeth said: if you set the path in cyberduck connection options, then you don't need a ListAllMyBuckets permission

Answer (score 22):

The selected answer didn't work for me, but this one did:

```json
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Credit: http://mikeferrier.com/2011/10/27/granting-access-to-a-single-s3-bucket-using-amazon-iam/

Comment: This allows listing of all buckets and doesn't limit access to just the bucket in question.

Comment: +1 for me: the voted one didn't work with Ruby's Fog gem but this conf worked of.

Comment: @Thanh Nguyen: Wrong. It will list all the buckets but will provide access only to the said bucket in the policy.

Comment: I needed this recipe to allow my IAM user to access the S3 console.

Answer (score 8):

Are you aware of the [AWS Policy Generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html)?

Comment: Yes, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: the policy generator raises more questions than it answers

Answer (score 6):

There is an official AWS documentation at [Writing IAM Policies: How to Grant Access to an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/)

Just copy and paste the appropriate rule and change the "Resource" key to your bucket's ARN in all Statements.

For **programamtic access** the policy should be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bar"]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bar/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And for **console access** access should be:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bar*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bar"]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::bar/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way I was recently able to get this to work was using Amazon's [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-console-access-certain-bucket/). The key for me was to point the IAM User **to the specific bucket NOT the S3 console**. Per the documentation, "Warning: After you change these permissions, the user gets an Access Denied error when they access the main Amazon S3 console. The main console link is similar to the following:

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home

Instead, the user must access the bucket using a direct console link to the bucket, similar to the following:

https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/awsexamplebucket/"

My policy is below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1589486662000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::AWSEXAMPLEBUCKET",
            "arn:aws:s3:::AWSEXAMPLEBUCKET/*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That works for me:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucketVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name_here"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*Object*",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name_here/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've been pulling your hair out because you cannot figure out why Cyberduck is not being able to set object ACLs but it works with another client (like Panic Transmit) here is the solution:

You need to add `s3:GetBucketAcl` to your Action list, eg:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Of course you don't need to do this if you are less restrictive with `s3:*` but I think this is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

@cloudberryman's answer is correct but I like to make things as short as possible. This answer can be reduced to:

```
{  
   "Statement":[  
      {  
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":"S3:*",
         "Resource":[  
            "arn:aws:s3:::bar",
            "arn:aws:s3:::bar/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: But your answer is not equivalent to cloudberryman.  Your example provides FULL access to the bucket AND the bucket contents, whereas his only allows list on the bucket but full access to the contents.  In your case, the privileges permit the bucket itself to be deleted, which might be more than most people want to grant.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                        "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
                      ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET",
                "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```