# Amazon access denied When trying to get the Bucket object list using java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am using Amazon S3 to upload/download videos. I can upload any video but I cannot list my videos in the bucket because I got these errors:

```
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: Error Message:    Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 4AEF68CB2979FBB9)
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: HTTP Status Code: 403
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: AWS Error Code:   AccessDenied
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: Error Type:       Client
03-30 11:51:06.911 28577-28734/com.video.apps3 I/CCC: Request ID:       4AEF68CB2979FBB9
```

I have a simple structure like this:

```
All Buckets/ myvideos/
  video1.mp4
  video2.mp4
  Other.mp4
```

I there is my policy for this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I can upload videos to it but I cannot list the elements inside.

It is the piece of code I am using to list the objects.

```
try {
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
            .withBucketName(MY_BUCKET)
            .withPrefix("")
            .withDelimiter("/");
    ObjectListing objectListing;
    do {
        objectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary :
                objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            Log.i("CCC", " - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                    "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() +
                    ")");
        }
        listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
    } while (objectListing.isTruncated());
} catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
    Log.i("CCC", "Caught an AmazonServiceException, " +
            "which means your request made it " +
            "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " +
            "for some reason.");    
    Log.i("CCC", "Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
    Log.i("CCC", "HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
    Log.i("CCC", "AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
    Log.i("CCC", "Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
    Log.i("CCC", "Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
} catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
    Log.i("CCC", "Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
            "which means the client encountered " +
            "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
            " with S3, " +
            "such as not being able to access the network.");
    Log.i("CCC", "Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
}
```

I don't know what else do I need to do? How is possible that with the same access S3 allow me to upload but denied the list?

### Update 1: Code

I was using this:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = 
    new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                context,
                IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
                MY_REGION
        );

AmazonS3  s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(MY_REGION));
```

And so I tried with this:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
```

And ok, It works. But I want to allow the videos access for no loggin users. I don't wanna use my **accessKey** and **secretKey**.

Comment: Try to extend the policy to include the bucket itself: `"Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos/*", "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos" ]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant access to the bucket for the ListBucket operation.  In your policy, you are granting access to the files inside the bucket `myvideos` but not the bucket itself.  Try this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos",
                "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To list the contents of the bucket add this to the policy

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
         "s3:ListBucket"
     ],
    "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::myvideos/*"
     ]
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8213772/4405757)